# Please help to identify SMD diode N2H

Tags: diodes, identification

I'm trying to repair a defective solar controller (Morningstar Tristar TS-MPPT 60) after a battery fuse failure. It probably caused to rise an output voltage rapidly, burn power MOSFETs and probably something in the processor switching supply (on the picture).

I've found some SMD caps shorted (where the capacitance is known by some wizzard and the Morningstar engineers only), and the red marked diode on the picture shows strange values (diode voltage measurement mode shows infinite in one direction and 1.7 V in opposite direction). Do you have any idea about the diode type (code N2H), please?

[image: "N2H" diode]

Comment: In-circuit-probing often isn't meaningful. Try to reverse-engineer the circuit this diode is part of to find out if there is another explanation for the 1.7V reading.

Comment: @SimSon Except on LED's I don't know any other diode with such high forward voltage. If you measure a diode in the forward direction, there should not be higher voltage, than the forward voltage. Otherwise it is damaged. No matter, if it is in any circuit, or not.

Comment: You can't be sure to actually measure the diode unless you know the circuit. If this was a TVS diode rated for a voltage higher than the voltage your MM uses to make the "diode test", then you would read "infinite" in both directions. The reading would be affected by the rest of the circuit. The circuit *could* even get partially powered by your MM...

Comment: TVS diodes have such small outline? It is a 4 layer PCB (this photo shows one tenth of the whole PCB) with coating, it is visibly impossible to follow the inner connections and not easy to destroy the coating - even for this measurement of one component. Just asked, if someone knows, how to identify the diode model. It is sad, that electronics went to a point, we mount components, that cannot be identified and replaced later. I have not seen any complete list of SMD codes so far.

Comment: TVS diodes can have any size, I worked with much smaller ones. That was just one example where a reading would be meaningless...

Comment: You don't neccessarily have to follow traces. Identify promiment components and imagine what the circuit does and how it works. Then you'll find out that, "oh, that's a voltage regulator, there might be a schottky diode somewhere close"... this way you can find a replacement without identifying components.

Comment: It is connected from base of the NPN Q53 to ground in parrallel with C71. This Q53 switches input to a LM5022 (U22 on the right bottom) supply mosfet (on top of the picture) driver. So it seems, it is really some kind of a "clipper", where a 1.7V clipping may be required.

Comment: According to the resistor divider in LM feedback it is a 12V power supply.